# Using the request body as cache key in AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to put an API Gateway in front of an external GraphQL API to cache its responses. I am currently facing the issue that GraphQL queries usually work by the client sending `POST` requests with the query in the request body in JSON format. If I was to enable caching, API Gateway would use the same cache key for every request because the request path stays the same even for different queries.

Is there a way to use the request body as cache key in AWS API Gateway?

Answer (score 1):

I believe, at least for REST API Gw (Integration request) that you can specify a header `bodyValue` mapped from `method.request.body` and there you can specify Caching enable or disable.

Comment: This worked for me when I was playing around. 

Two things to do:
Step 1.
`update resources` -> `<graphql POST>` -> `Integration Request` -> `HTTP Headers` -> `bodyValue` = `method.request.body`  (and tick) `Caching`

deploy this stage change 

Part 2

`stages` -> `apiStage` -> `<graphql POST>` ->  `Override for this method` & `Enable Method Cache`


I used these documents as well as GET is only cached. [AWS cache docco](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-caching.html#override-api-gateway-stage-cache-for-method-cache)